# Spawning random different objects at random locations

Tags: libgdx

I am making a game where there are different objects fall from the upper part of the screen to the lower part of the screen. I am having problems with how can I choose what TextureRegion randomly to be spawned and not to change the already spawned TextureRegions. When I run the game lets say that the electronRegion is spawned first then when the next is spawned and let's say it's an antiprotonRegion the first electronRegion changes to antiprotonRegion that I don't want.

Here is my game class:

```
public class GameScreenTest implements Screen {
...

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    camera.update();

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.disableBlending();
    game.batch.draw(background, 0, 0);
    game.batch.enableBlending();
    for(Particles particle: particles) {
        particlesControl.draw(particle.x, particle.y);
    }
    game.batch.end();

    if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastDropTime > 500) {
        particlesControl.spawn();
        particlesControl.update();
    }

    Iterator<Particles> iter = particles.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Particles particle = iter.next();
        particle.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(particle.y + particle.height < 0) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}

...

private class Particles {

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    private Particles() {
    }

    private void spawn() {
        Particles particle = new Particles();
        particle.x = MathUtils.random(0, 480 - width);
        particle.y = 800;
        particle.width = width;
        particle.height = height;
        particles.add(particle);
        lastDropTime = TimeUtils.millis();
    }

    private void update() {
        choice = MathUtils.random(1, 4);
        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                chosen = new TextureRegion(protonRegion);
                width = 75;
                height = 75;
                break;
            case 2:
                chosen = new TextureRegion(electronRegion);
                width = 75 / 2;
                height = 75 / 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                chosen = new TextureRegion(antiprotonRegion);
                width = 75;
                height = 75;
                break;
            case 4:
                chosen = new TextureRegion(antielectronRegion);
                width = 75 / 2;
                height = 75 / 2;
                break;
        }
    }
    private void draw(int x, int y) {
        game.batch.draw(chosen, x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

I want to know why does all the spawned objects change every time a random choice is taken, and of course, how to solve this problem. Thank You.

Comment: Okay so even through you code is kind of messy, your problem is that your **chosen** variable belongs to the **GameScreenTest** class and the **Particles** is an inner class. In the Particles to choose a texture and to draw it you are using the **chosen** which will always be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Tray this:

```
public class GameScreenTest implements Screen {

    final AntimatterBlast game;

    private Texture gameObjects;

    private TextureRegion electronRegion;
    private TextureRegion antielectronRegion;
    private TextureRegion protonRegion;
    private TextureRegion antiprotonRegion;

//===========================================//
//remove private TextureRegion chosen;
//===========================================//

    private TextureRegion background;

    private Music gameMusic;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    private Array<Particles> particles;

    private Particles particlesControl;

    private long lastDropTime;

    private int choice;

    public GameScreenTest(final AntimatterBlast game) {
    this.game = game;

    gameObjects = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("GameObjects.png"));

    electronRegion = new TextureRegion(gameObjects, 105, 103, 50, 50);

    antielectronRegion = new TextureRegion(gameObjects, 105, 155, 46, 46);

    protonRegion = new TextureRegion(gameObjects, 6, 6, 100, 100);

    antiprotonRegion = new TextureRegion(gameObjects, 6, 108, 90, 90);

    background = new TextureRegion(gameObjects, 0, 204, 480, 800);

    gameMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("DST-ElektroHauz.mp3"));

    gameMusic.setLooping(true);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    camera.setToOrtho(false, 480, 800);

    particles = new Array<Particles>();

    particlesControl = new Particles();

//===========================================//
//choice = MathUtils.random(1, 4);           //remove
//chosen = new TextureRegion(protonRegion);  //remove
//===========================================//

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    camera.update();

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.disableBlending();
    game.batch.draw(background, 0, 0);
    game.batch.enableBlending();

    for(Particles particle: particles) {
    //===========================================//
    particlesControl.draw(particle.chosen, particle.x, particle.y);
    //change
    //particlesControl.draw(particle.x, particle.y);
    //===========================================//
    }

    game.batch.end();

    if(TimeUtils.millis() - lastDropTime > 500) {

    //===========================================//
    particlesControl.spawn();
    //===========================================//

    //===========================================//
    //remove particlesControl.update();
    //===========================================//
    }

        Iterator<Particles> iter = particles.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            Particles particle = iter.next();
            particle.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(particle.y + particle.height < 0) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        gameMusic.play();
        particlesControl.spawn();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        gameObjects.dispose();
        gameMusic.dispose();
    }


    private class Particles {

        //===========================================//
        private TextureRegion chosen; //add variable
        //===========================================//

        private int width;
        private int height;
        private int x;
        private int y;

        private Particles() {

        }

        private void spawn() {

            Particles particle = new Particles();
            particle.x = MathUtils.random(0, 480 - width);
            particle.y = 800;
            particle.width = width;
            particle.height = height;

            //===========================================//
            particle.selectTexture();
            //===========================================//

            lastDropTime = TimeUtils.millis();

            //===========================================//
            selectTexture(); //add call
            //===========================================//

            particles.add(particle);
        }

        //===========================================//
        private void selectTexture() { //change name, but is not nesesari
        //===========================================//
            choice = MathUtils.random(1, 4);
            switch(choice) {
                case 1:
                   //===========================================//
                   //change
                   //chosen = new TextureRegion(antielectronRegion);
                   //if you are not going to change or modific TextureRegion 
                   //independet other the textureRegion, 
                   //I think you could use it well.It is just an idea
                   chosen = protonRegion;
                   //===========================================//

                    width = 75;
                    height = 75;
                    break;
                case 2:
                   //===========================================//
                   //change
                   //chosen = new TextureRegion(antielectronRegion);
                   //if you are not going to change or modific TextureRegion 
                   //independet other the textureRegion, 
                   //I think you could use it well.It is just an idea
                   chosen = electronRegion;
                   //===========================================//

                    width = 75 / 2;
                    height = 75 / 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                   //===========================================//
                   //change
                   //chosen = new TextureRegion(antielectronRegion);
                   //if you are not going to change or modific TextureRegion 
                   //independet other the textureRegion, 
                   //I think you could use it well.It is just an idea
                   chosen = antiprotonRegion;
                   //===========================================//

                    width = 75;
                    height = 75;
                    break;
                case 4:
                   //===========================================//
                   //change
                   //chosen = new TextureRegion(antielectronRegion);
                   //if you are not going to change or modific TextureRegion 
                   //independet other the textureRegion, 
                   //I think you could use it well.It is just an idea
                   chosen = antielectronRegion;
                   //===========================================//

                    width = 75 / 2;
                    height = 75 / 2;
                    break;
            }
        }
        //===========================================//
        private void draw(TextureRegion chosen, int x, int y) {
            game.batch.draw(chosen, x, y, width, height);
        //===========================================//
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfournately, it didn't work. Actually, there is no difference at all. The objects still change during after being spawned. I am really happy that you are trying to help. Thank you!

Comment: @Abdel-Rahman Amr Now test if it works I do not think I'll delete my answer luck

Comment: Hello @AngelAngel :) does your code even compile? :P I see you corrected one of the problems I mentioned. But in your spawn() you commented Particles particle ( because you wanted to use the constructor and not have an infinite recursion ) but particle no longer exists in that scope

Comment: @Opetion Hello I think the mistake was in TextureRegion chosen, but he said it did not work, I made some changes so I put test because I really can not run this code, I also mentioned that if it did not work now erase the answer

Comment: hey at least you are trying to help, but there are many issues with the code :\ I'm currently at work but i'm going to list a few of the problems in the main question comments and if you guys still need help i'll try to build a more elaborate answer later at night.

Comment: @Opetion I'm mainly responded because he believed that the error was the texture, but then told me not working, and change some things but if true it has errors or things that I think should not to be, well think i check only change on the texture, if you want to modify the answer

Comment: Your code got me a runtime error but I fixed the problem with some code editing. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanAmr did you manage to solve the problem of the question than?

Comment: @Opetion Yes, I did, although, I don't fully understand why it's solved.

Comment: ok from what I saw of Angel's code the main thing that was changed was where the **chosen** variable was declared. When you declared it you declared outside of the Particles class ( inner class not sure if you ever heard about it but you are using it :) ) since you declared it outside it belongs to the GameScreenTest class and there is only 1 of it. In the Particles class even through you can access the variables from GameScreenTest they still belong to the class, and every time you create a particle they are using the GameScreenTest variable not their own. ( hopefully you understood better )

Comment: It is all about the Scope of the variables http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html hopefully this link might help you. @Abdel-RahmanAmr ( forgot to mention you in the previous comment )

Comment: @Abdel-RahmanAmr :) good luck and best of luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the previous comment the texture (**chosen**) is in the GameScreenTest and you are using it in the inner class so every single instance of the **Particles** class will share the same texture.

---

Not error causing but it might help you to organize the code and make it more readable and by all means you are not obligated to make them just take them as suggestions:

**Naming conventions**
Naming the class Particles make it seem like the class represents more than 1 Particle, but in fact it represents a single Particle maybe name it only Particle.

**Separating the game logic**
Make the Particle class deal only with its own problems and **don't** use it to generate other particles and to add it to an outer class.

**Using the constructor since it is already there**
Give the Particle the texture that it should use and maybe the coordinates.

**Drawing "dead" particle**
You are drawing first and asking questions later depending on your game it might feel weird since you will always draw a frame while it no longer exists.

**Not really sure on this one**
But you might be able to reuse the textures regions instead of a creating a new one of the same texture for every single particle

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tips. About reusing, I'll be working on this after I am done with some other bugs in the game. Thank you!

Comment: @Abdel-Rahman Amr If this answer helped your problem, you can consider upvote Thanks